# How can I convert a string (array of maps) into a struct in GOLANG?

Tags: json, api, go

I am trying to convert this json-format string into an actual json object in GOLANG.

`{"predictions": [{"predictions": [4492.0]}, {"predictions": [4515.84716796875]}, {"predictions": [4464.86083984375]}]}`

Basically, it is a dictionary with a key "predictions" and the value es an array of dictionaries (each dictionary is has as a key "predictions" and a value an 1-element float array. I created two structure (one for the first dictionary and the other one for the array of dictionaries), but I can't fit the string json to my structure. I am not sure what I am missing

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)


type dataPredictions struct {
    SinglePredictions *SinglePredictions `json:"predictions"`
}

type SinglePredictions struct {
    Predictions []map[string]int `json:predictions`
}

func main() {

    s := `{"predictions": [{"predictions": [4492.0]}, {"predictions": [4515.84716796875]}, {"predictions": [4464.86083984375]}]}`

    data := &dataPredictions{
        SinglePredictions: &SinglePredictions{},
    }
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), data)
  s2, _ := json.Marshal(data)
    fmt.Println(err)
    fmt.Println(data.SinglePredictions)
    fmt.Println(string(s2))

}
```

The error I get is below.

```
json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field dataPredictions.predictions of type main.SinglePredictions
```

Comment: Note that you aren't unmarshalling into a "JSON object". The original string is a JSON object, you're unmarshalling it into a Go struct.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two mistakes. The first is that you didn't define SinglePredictions as a slice, which is why you got the error in the first place, and then you used the map when you simply needed to pass down `[]float64`.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type dataPredictions struct {
    SinglePredictions []*SinglePredictions `json:"predictions"`
}

type SinglePredictions struct {
    Predictions []float64 `json:"predictions"`
}

func main() {
    s := `{"predictions": [{"predictions": [4492.0]}, {"predictions": [4515.84716796875]}, {"predictions": [4464.86083984375]}]}`
    // Note that you don't need to assign values manually - json.Unmarshal
    // will do that for you.
    data := &dataPredictions{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), data)
    s2, _ := json.Marshal(data)
    fmt.Println(err)
    fmt.Println(data.SinglePredictions)
    fmt.Println(string(s2))

}
```

The mistake you made seems that to have been thinking that Go would have unmarshalled the first array into `dataPredictions.SinglePredictions.Predictions`. But in `dataPredictions` you have a field which selects the `"predictions"` key in the topmost object, and its value is then passed to unmarshal into a `*SinglePredictions`

Comment: Why do you put an asterisk (*) in []*SinglePredictions? it seems to work fine without it, what's the difference?

Comment: There is a difference, but in this context it does not really matter and you can leave it out. I just copied it from the code of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)


type dataPredictions struct {
    SinglePredictions []SinglePredictions `json:"predictions"`
}

type SinglePredictions struct {
    Predictions []float64 `json:"predictions"`
}

func main() {
    s := []byte(`{"predictions": [{"predictions": [4492.0]}, {"predictions": [4515.84716796875]}, {"predictions": [4464.86083984375]}]}`)

    data := dataPredictions{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(s, &data)
    s2, _ := json.Marshal(data)
    fmt.Println(err)
    fmt.Println(data.SinglePredictions)
    fmt.Println(string(s2))
}
```